# DO i need sqllite for symfony2 in php

Tags: php, symfony

I am installing symfony 2 on server but i don't have sqlite but mysql.

But config.php says that i need sqllite3.

Is that must or i can work with mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite is only used for the web profiler. You can disable the profiler and it won't complain about sqlite.

Remove this from your AppKernel.php

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
```

or preferably install `php-sqlite`

I believe the profiler actually falls back to flat-file if sqlite cannot be used anyway. So I would say you can safely ignore the message from config.php